# Remotely control application settings

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, remote-access

I have a solution that acts as client service and does some background work. This application requires some settings (that are read from an xml file) to be done at installation time and which are periodically revised. For convenience (as this service is installed on multiple machines) I wanted to control these settings remotely from a central server application. This works fine if the server and client are inside the LAN but I would like to control these settings even if the client is outside the network or the server is behind a firewall. What could be the solutions to do this?

Comment: Are you sure all your clients would appreciate this? And their security officers?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the solution depends on exactly what you want to achieve. But if I understand it right, the reason you have "problems" with a firewall is that you simply access the file that contains the XML over the network using standard network file access. Which is typically (for good reason) blocked by the firewall.

So, the solution then would be to use a standard protocol and a "non-standard service". For example, if the machine is allowed incomming HTTP requests, you could use HTTP-based post messages to update the XML content, either send the entire file as a file upload, or make up your own remote access protocol. If HTTP is not allowed, then you have to look at what other "holes" there are in the firewall, and do something similar with another of the "holes".

The other, less obscure solution, is of course to simply use a remote-desktop or secure shell connection to remotely access the machine. Of course, again, assuming this sort of connection is allowed.

There is no magical "bypass firewall" solution - you have to work within the rules of the firewall in some way.

Comment: I was thinking about using an intermediary public server that would serve all the client services but I would not like the intermediary server to store the settings files (as I don't have the necessary hardware), but only to intermediate the communication between the client services and the server that has the settings, something similar to how the bittorent protocol works.. But I'm not sure how to make a connection between the client service and the settings server if they are in different networks. Maybe I could use a STUN server implementation or port-forwarding..